# Identify the required (missing) certificate that's causing a Java app to fail

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I'm using Intellij IDEA 15, a Java-based IDE.   It allows me to click on a link in any open-source Java class in my project and download the source and documentation from the internet.   However, this feature is failing right now because we have to go through a proxy server, which does certificate substitution.   Although the Windows system I'm on knows about the local certificate, the Java VM I'm using doesn't know about it, so the download process fails with this error:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The solution would seem to be to export the proper certificate from my Windows box's certificate store and add it to the JVM certificate store in `/jre/lib/security/cacert`, except that I have no idea which one of the dozens of certificates in the Windows store is missing.

Can anyone suggest a debugging method to identify which certificate is missing?   In my own code I would set a breakpoint using Intellij and look at the values being passed, but since the problem is **inside Intellij** I really don't know how to get to these values.

Any help is appreciated, if this needs to be moved to a different StackExchange community I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy servers are always fun!

Okay. The trick when it comes to tracking down cert issues is that *the root cert is the most important one*. The root certificate of the [chain of trust](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/) is a CA, and if your system trusts the CA, it also trusts anything it signs. Conversely, if the CA is not trusted, anything it signs is invalid.

Your Windows is configured to trust the CA, probably courtesy of the local IT department. Java, however, is not.

Therefore: You need to get the CA key that is generating certs on your proxy server, and insert that into your Java keystore.

You can probably find this by opening up any secure site on any web browser, opening the page properties, and taking a look at the actual certificate. On Firefox, that looks something like this:

[image: Firefox cert properties]

You'd click on the top level one, here called "COMODO ECC Certification Authority", export it, and then use the java `keytool` to install it as a CA.

Note: On your setup, the name **will certainly be different.** Chances are, it won't be the name of a company known for certificates like Comodo or Verisign, it'll be the name of an equipment vendor like Barracuda or Bluecoat

Further details on the workings of `keytool` on Windows are [available here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/java-add-certificate-ca-store/)